# Unable to extract surface pressure value from ERA 5 on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a point coordinate value, and I am trying to extract the surface pressure value and export it to a CSV file from the ERA5 Hourly dataset on google earth engine; however, I am getting an error List.get, argument 'list': Invalid type. Expected type: List. Actual type: Float. Actual value: 99456.6416015625 (Error code: 3). I was able to use the same code to extract the u component and the v component of the wind. Here is my code snippet.

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([77.1272, 28.8107]);
Map.addLayer(point);
Map.centerObject(point);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY");

var startDate = ee.Date('2019-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2021-01-01');
var diff = endDate.difference(startDate, 'day');

var ucomponent = dataset.select('surface_pressure')
              .filterDate(startDate, endDate);
var list_ucomponent = ucomponent.toList(dataset.size());

var getucomponent = function(image) {

var value_ucomponent = ee.Image(image)
.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), point)
.get('surface_pressure');
 var time = ee.Image(image).get('system:time_start');
 return value_ucomponent;
 }

 var u_list = list_ucomponent.map(getucomponent);

 var allDates = ee.List(ucomponent.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));
 
 var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
 return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
 }).distinct();

 var len = u_list.size();
 var list = ee.List.sequence(0, len.subtract(1), 24);

 var mean_u_list = list.map(function(ele){

 var start = ee.Number(ele).int(); 
 var end = ee.Number(ele).add(24).int(); 

 var new_list = ee.List([]);
 var element = ee.List(u_list.slice(start, end)).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());

 new_list = new_list.add(element);

 return new_list;

 }).flatten();

 var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(mean_u_list.map(function(el){
 el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list
 var geom = point;
 return ee.Feature(geom, {
'date': ee.String(el.get(0)),
'values':ee.List(el.get(1))
});
}));

Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"hourly", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder
"hourly_data",  //file name
"CSV");
```

I am very new to Google Earth Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is produced because you are trying to map a wrong list (**mean_u_list** doesn't have dates). Fixed list is named paired in following script (it includes dates now). It has the properties date and values that you want to export. By the way, I reduced the dates range for speeding up the export process.

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([77.1272, 28.8107]);
Map.addLayer(point);
Map.centerObject(point);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY");

var startDate = ee.Date('2019-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2019-02-01');
var diff = endDate.difference(startDate, 'day');

var ucomponent = dataset.select('surface_pressure')
              .filterDate(startDate, endDate);
var list_ucomponent = ucomponent.toList(dataset.size());

var getucomponent = function(image) {

  var value_ucomponent = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), point)
    .get('surface_pressure');
    var time = ee.Image(image).get('system:time_start');
    return value_ucomponent;
};

var u_list = list_ucomponent.map(getucomponent);

var allDates = ee.List(ucomponent.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));
 
var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
 
 return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);

}).distinct();

var len = u_list.size();
var list = ee.List.sequence(0, len.subtract(1), 24);

var mean_u_list = list.map(function(ele){

var start = ee.Number(ele).int(); 
var end = ee.Number(ele).add(24).int(); 

var new_list = ee.List([]);
var element = ee.List(u_list.slice(start, end)).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());

new_list = new_list.add(element);

  return new_list;

}).flatten();

print(mean_u_list);

var paired = allDatesSimple.zip(mean_u_list);

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(paired.map(function(el){

  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'date': ee.List(el).get(0),
    'values': ee.List(el).get(1)
  });
}));

print(myFeatures);

Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"hourly", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder
"hourly_data",  //file name
"CSV");
```

After running it in GEE code editor, task produces result as expected.